# Correctly display the columns in a PivotTable

Tags: mysql, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel. I have field headings on my other sheet I have got the date in them that correspond with a name.

When I make the pivot table all of the columns that have different amounts of data in them all show the same total. It is almost like it is counting the blanks.

Please look at the pictures and tell me if I am doing something wrong.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpMzX.png] 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUAxr.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is counting the blanks -- even though there is nothing in the cell, there may be formatting or other aspects that the pivot will include in the count.  To fix this, you can either:

1. Filter your raw data and filter each column to just show the (Blanks).  Highlight the entire column and press delete
2. Instead of "Yes" use 1.  In your pivot instead of "Count" choose the value field setting of "Count Numbers"